# how can i get connection bandwidth used per process under windows os?

Tags: .net, windows

i would like to know about software that can do this and if it is possible to be programmed under the .net framework. please dont post irrelevant software! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to program it, you'll have to sniff network traffic, it might be done via WinPCap driver for example.

If you want a working program, you may take any sniffer like free SmartSniff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that network information is stored *by process*, but only for entire system:

```
// using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
foreach (var network in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    IPv4InterfaceStatistics stats = network.GetIPv4Statistics();
    Console.WriteLine("In={0}, Out={1}", stats.BytesReceived, stats.BytesSent);
}
```