# Getting per connection bandwidth statistics

Tags: c#, windows, networking, netstat, iphelper

I need to determine per-process network usage statistics similar to what TCPView can do.

[Example http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/861/6601f15814544055a590e26.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/861/6601f15814544055a590e26.png)

So before you shoot me for posting a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630285/programmatically-getting-per-process-network-statistics-on-windows), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077798/how-can-i-get-connection-bandwidth-used-per-process-under-windows-os), I would like to point out that neither of those have a thorough answer that could help me actually do this.

I've been doing research, and there are clearly many ways to list out active connections and their associated processes, whether this be with netstat or other windows API's like [IpHlpAPI.dll](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4298/Getting-active-TCP-UDP-connections-on-a-box).

Now, from what Google'ing I've done, I have not found much - except for these vague terms: **[GetPerTcpConnectionEStats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485738(v=vs.85).aspx)** and **[GetPerTcp6ConnectionEStats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485735(v=vs.85).aspx)**. Presumably for TCP over IPv4 and IPv6 respectively. Now where I was reading its supposedly able to do what I need to do. However, that still leaves out UDP. And those are also not available on XP systems, which TCPViewer works on.

I would be satisfied with using those for TCP, but the problem is, I can't seem to find any examples of how to use them from C#.

So I guess it all boils down to these few questions:

- Does anyone actually know how TCPView does it?
- How do I use GetPerTcpConnectionEStats for the TCP? Or can it even accomplish what I'm suggesting?
- Is there another known alternative that would work for UDP?

The whole point of this is to see the independent bandwidth usage of the processes themselves. Not calculate the total system bandwidth usage.

Thanks in advance for any and all answers.

Comment: It is very likely you can do this via WMI / performance counters, however I personally find those APIs rather arcane... just in case you get no good answers and are looking for further keywords to google.

Comment: @TomerPeled: I never did find a solution, and abandoned the project (as it was personal anyways). If you do find out how to determine the bandwidth usage of individual processes though, please post it as an answer and it might spark some motivation in me to finish up my old project :)

Answer (score 2):

I spent a bit of time trying to figure out how I'd do something similar (latency vs bandwidth) but have had to give up due to a lack of time to invest.  I thought I'd add my findings here in the hope we eventually get an answer.

You'll obviously need to use PInvoke and I'm afraid the specifics are far beyond my experience with it.

This [Wrapper Library on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4298/Getting-active-TCP-UDP-connections-on-a-box) uses [AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365804%28v=vs.85%29) which only works on Windows XP and Server 2003.  It still doesn't get you bandwidth though sorry.

The closest information I could find as a starting point (for Vista/Server 2008 or newer) is an example on pinvoke.net for [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.GetExtendedTcpTable).

The tool [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) might help determine how to call the unmanaged code.

If I were to keep trying this I'd try to figure out the following:

1. How to call [SetPerTcpConnectionEStats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb451840%28v=vs.85%29) to enable collection of TcpConnectionEstatsBandwidth via the appropriate [TCP_ESTATS_TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb427395%28v=vs.85%29).
2. I'd use [IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the information needed to create a [MIB_TCPROW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366909%28v=vs.85%29).
3. Determine how to call [GetPerTcpConnectionEStats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb485738%28v=vs.85%29) to monitor the data.